# Deny specific chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a constraint or something similar, which only allows chars like `A-Z`, `_` and `-` in a column.

How can this be done?

Comment: it's about MS SQL 2008r2, not mySQL!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this..It Work Fine In ms sql server

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(ID INT, FirstCol VARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT FirstCol CHECK (FirstCol NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z\_-]%' ESCAPE '\'))
```

Comment: LIKE, not NOT LIKE. ("only allows chars like A-Z, _ and - .")

Comment: @jarlh - it's a double-negative because we know the characters to allow and don't want to list all of the characters to not allow (note the `^` inside the `[]`). So `NOT LIKE` is correct here.

Comment: Sorry, too early for me... Didn't notice the ^. But why not just "LIKE '%[a-zA-Z\_-]%' ESCAPE '\'"?

Comment: @jarlh - because that would match any string which contains *any characters*, then one character from the given set, then *any characters*. Those *any characters* could be *anything*. Instead, we use `LIKE` to find a string which contains *any characters*, then one banned character, then *any characters*. When we apply `NOT` to that, by implication, the string does not contain any banned characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex-constraints if they are supported.

An example using **PostgreSQL** looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    name VARCHAR
    CONSTRAINT constraint_name CHECK (name ~* '^[A-Z_-]*$')
);
```

Note that this regular expression allows empty strings and no lower case characters.

Otherwise (in case of **MySQL**)  you can use an insert-trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF (NEW.phone REGEXP '^[A-Z_-]*$' ) = 0 THEN 
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid content';
    END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For **MS SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    name VARCHAR(100) CHECK (name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z_-]%'
))
```